# Fixing LCD Panel on LED backlit monitor

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I have a Samsung S22C300B monitor which was manufactured in week 35 2013 and bought in October 2013. This had a 5 year warranty which ended last year. So here is my problem -

[image]

If anyone can help me fix this, it would be really great since I'm not in a position to buy a new monitor at the moment.
I do have an extra AOC monitor which was made in 2011 but unfortunately the EDID is corrupted on its' DVI port and is not detected by my RX 570. AOC monitor works fine with both my old graphics cards GTX 460 and 760, and also the onboard Intel GPU even though none of the cards are able to detect the monitor model and sees it as Standard Non Plug and Play Monitor, while all GPUs detect the Samsung S22C300B immediately with the model number.

Both monitors had been out of use for about 2 years and had some amount of fungus growing inside them (on LED backlight diffusers and edges of LCD) no thanks to our warm humid climate (average 30°C and 90% humidity). Managed to take both monitors apart and clean out the fungus so no traces are visible on the LCD or backlight.

Unfortunately, the Samsung had also developed a single blue line while the AOC didn't have any picture issues apart from the fungus after these two years. The single line was joined by another yellow line after a few days and now daily another line seems to be appearing :(

So, any help at all, to fix the panel on the Samsung in the picture or even to fix EDID on the AOC so that I have some sort of usable monitor would be extremely appreciated!

Notes -
1. This is not a Windows issue, it's present even with signal cables unplugged
2. It's not an issue with the logic board on the Samsung, since I plugged in the AOC panel while both were disassembled and no lines were present. Sadly, the tabs are on top of the Samsung panel while at the bottom of the AOC panel and frames don't match either.
3. Pressing and cleaning the tabs with isopropyl alcohol did not change anything with the panel, did not get rid of the lines nor did new lines appear.
4. Samsung panel displayed same lines when connected to the AOC logic board. But again, missing EDID on the logic board prevents it from working with the AMD card.

Comment: Your picture doesn't show a back panel lighting issue - the lighting is working. It shows a dead LCD panel or more probably a bad internal cable issue. Mould & electronics is not a happy marriage. You warranty would have been invalid anyway under those circumstances.

Comment: Or a small crack under the frame.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, yes the LED backlights are working fine but issue seems to be with the second tab from the left, six tabs in total on this size/type of panels. The frame is very sturdy on this monitor and quite thick as well, and did not observe any apparent damage when taken apart. It barely came apart unlike the AOC. The logic board to panel cable is also fine since the panel from the AOC worked fine with the same ribbon. So, any advise on fixing the tabs if so? Thanks again!